# Rails - go to index, but also submit form with the same click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I have a redirect that works fine for getting me to my index. It is below:

```
redirect_to action: :index, filters: { recent_price_change: "#{1.week.ago.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')} - #{Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')}" }, hide_filters: true
```

Thing is, I am populating a filter on click. On that same page is a button that is tagged with the submit action.

here is the excerpt of the HAML (it's sorta kinda like ERB... don't worry much on it, just note how it is type: submit) file containing it:

```
  %button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm{ type: 'submit', style: 'background-color: #a38672;' }
   %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-play
   Update List
```

Clicking the button above submits the form, which applies the filter put some results in a table on the screen.

This was/is all fine and good - but there is a new requirement where I want that submit button to be "automatically clicked" on redirect. AKA, I don't want to have to click this button manually ... instead, as part of the redirect, the form needs to be submitted. So when the page loads, it is AS IF I had just clicked the button - the data is populated, etc. Do you all know if this is possible/how I would do it? I have dug through documentation for the redirect_to action hoping I would find some help there - but no dice as of yet.

UPDATE:

I added:

```
document.querySelector('.button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm').click();
```

Onto the haml at the end of the file like so:

```
:javascript
   document.querySelector('.button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm').click();
```

It does submit the form on load... but turns out my index page must be getting re-rendered over and over... it repeatedly clicks the button. It doesn't do it just once. Was wondering if there is some way to bind this just to onload.

UPDATE 2:

So I wrote

```
firstSubmit = function() {
  document.querySelector('.button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm').click();
};
 $(document).on('page:load', firstSubmit);
```

The problem is... seems my page is reloading itself repeatedly. So then, it spams my button over and over, leading to total flux of the page. Anyway to limit this without getting really janky (global var? - I'd hate to)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add flag variable to form (assume form action redirects to `index`):

```
= hidden_field_tag :do_not_redirect  
%button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm{ type: 'submit', style: 'background-color: #a38672;' }
  %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-play
  Update List
```

Then modify javascript:

```
- unless params[:do_not_redirect]
  :javascript
    $(document).on('page:load', function () {
      $('#do_not_redirect').val(1);
      $('.button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm').click();
    });
```

And controller:

```
redirect_to action: :index, filters: {
  recent_price_change: "#{1.week.ago.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')} - #{Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')}"
}, hide_filters: true, do_not_redirect: params[:do_not_redirect].presence
```

Comment: Hey there - so I sort of naively put this code in, and so far, no dice. But wanted to ask how is this trying to invoke? If do_not_redirect is tied to my button as a flag variable, is it not the case that, since the person is not ever hitting the button (ideally - want it to load without ever hitting the button), it never gets populated, and hence, the form never submits? I think if I can better understand what we are trying to do here, I can get it together/figure out how to get it working in my situation.

Comment: `do_not_redirect` field sets by javascript automatically when page loads and then  submits form; controller checks presence of do_not_redirect POST parameter and redirects to index with this flag in GET params; javascript does not appear, when flag presents, and form submits only once.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is utilize a callback. Not sure if you're familiar, but a callback is just a routine that you run after some other action has taken place. In this case, after you click the submit button (which would most likely be an after_save or after_commit callback), you want to redirect to the index. Callbacks are generally found at the top of the controller in a case like this, something like the following:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    after_save :go_to_index
```

Then, after your normal controller actions:

```
    private
    def go_to_index
        // Redirect code
    end
```

I think this is what you're looking for, you can find the callback api info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html.

Comment: Hey there, I actually do not want the button to ever be pressed. Essentially, I want the button press to be emulated - I want the button press to be "automatic" as soon as you hit the landing page.

Comment: Doesn't it lead to the landing page?